# MongoParseError: option usemongoclient is not supported

Tags: mongoose, node-modules, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make a Cutomer CLI model but it gives me an error when I run the following command:

`node commands.js add John Doe 555-555-5555 john@gmail.com`

The error which I recieve again and again is:

```
C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:272
        throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);
              ^

MongoParseError: option usemongoclient is not supported
    at parseOptions (C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:272:15)
    at new MongoClient (C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:48:63)
    at _createMongoClient (C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:887:14)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:742:29)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:406:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mrmik\Desktop\code\PROJECTS\Customer CLI\index.js:6:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

The code which I tried was in a file named **commands.js**.
The code was:

```
const program = require('commander'); 
const{
   addCustomer, 
   findCustomer
} = require('./index'); 

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .description('Client Management System')

program 
    .command('add <firstname> <lastname> <phone> <email>')
    .alias('a')
    .description('Add a customer')
    .action((firstname, lastname, phone, email) => {
        addCustomer({firstname, lastname, phone, email}); 
    }); 

program 
    .command('find <name>')
    .alias('f')
    .description('Find a customer')
    .action(name => findCustomer(name)); 

program.parse(process.argv);
```